# Determine expected goals from two normal distributions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, density-function, function

Assume Team A scores an average of 3 goals per game with a standard deviation of 1.0, and assuming Team B allows an average of 2 goals per game with a standard deviation of 0.5.

How would you determine the expected goals of Team A scoring on Team B?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to model goals scored with a normal distribution because the normal distribution spans all real numbers, and it wouldn't make sense for a team to score, for example, 2.236 goals in a game. Modeling goals using a Poisson distribution makes sense because possible values are restricted to nonnegative integers. Using a Poisson distribution will give you a more straightforward way of answering this question.

Comment: Since this doesn't actually answer the question, although it is a good and useful statement, it should really be a comment instead of an answer.  Note also that the Poisson doesn't fit the information given, as the variances don't equal the means in the problem statement.

Comment: This question doesn't supply enough information to be answerable, because it offers nothing about how goals scored might be associated with goals scored against.

Comment: Ignoring the real world and assuming that this is a badly flawed question asking for the mean and variance of the sum of two **independent normal** random variables, you have $A\sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_a = 3,\sigma_a = 1),$ $B\sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_b = 2,\sigma_b=1/2).$ And then you'd have $A+B\sim\mathsf{Norm}(3+2=5, \sqrt{1^2+(1/2)^2} = \sqrt{1.25}).$